# Deploy an Azure Webjob from ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to know if it is possible to create an Azure webjob with visual studio 2019, then host it in my azureDevOps account and finally deploy it within my ARM template calling the project using a URL in order to automate the whole procces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Follow the below links.

[Develop WebJobs in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs)

[Deploy WebJobs using Azure DevOps](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/deploying-dotnet-core-webjobs-to-azure-using-azure-pipelines)